# Routing Error: 2 routes are triggered when link is clicked, yet on client side it works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I cannot find out why when that following route:

```
get "/instagram", to: "posts#instagram", as: "instagram"
```

is requested by this code:

```
<%= link_to "Instagram", instagram_path %>
```

and perfectly render:

```
posts/instagram.html.erb
```

via the `PostsController` and following action:

```
def instagram
end
```

it does render `posts/instagram.html.erb` but it also try to get to this weird URL `GET "/..."` that I did not set up in my `routes.rb` or any where in the rails app.

Everything works fine on the client side and if not looking at the logs I may never have noticed this, but it bother me that this error is triggered: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/...")` as it does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that any ajax function is called when you click on the link, first you should check jquery is not causing the issue.

Second you should check by disabling turbolink, for particular link you can data-no-turbolink to disable turbolink.

Also try in different browser.

Comment: Yes it is what I though but I only have one AJAX request and it is for another route. as regards to trying diff browser I tried safari and firefox both trigger that error. I will investigate on the turbolink idea that you sugested.

Comment: the best way to check if JavaScript causing issue is disable the browser JavaScript for temporary. To disable JavaScript in firefox got url   about:config and search the line javascript:enabled to disable it double click on it and once you tested again double click on it to re-enable JavaScript.